# Cell is not formatted as expected (date format) and formula is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to format a cell on Date format to apply `MINIFS` formula on the column.

I changed from menu "Format Cell" from `Text` to `Date`. However it is no solving the issue.

`MINIFS` still returning `#VALUE!` or `01/01/1900`.

Value in the cell is `2020-05-15` and expected format is `15/05/2020`.

I getting this value from a SQL extract.

Did you already faced this behavior ?

Thank you

Comment: guess would be that the value is a string and not yet converted to a date value - what happens when you use `VALUE(whatever)` as an argument for `minifs` or you create a helper column which is `=value(original column)` and pass that to `minifs`?

Comment: Indeed it is helping me. Thank you